# How can I catch / report the error elmah hits when trying to send an e-mail?

Tags: c#, email, elmah

We are using Elmah to handle our errors, and on some of our servers it is working beautifully but on others it is logging and processing the error but not sending the e-mail.  I imagine Elmah is hitting some sort of problem sending the mail but I have no way to see what this problem is.

How can I catch and report (even if just logging to the console or a file) errors Elmah itself hits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Checkout source](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/source/checkout), build from there, attach dll`s to Your application, start application in webdev, attach studio that has elmah project opened to webdev, re-produce error and see exactly what's happening.

But in Your case, I would double check if network settings are ok. Seems to me that smtp ports are closed or something. Create small console app that sends e-mails and try to run it on server or use telnet.

Comment: We did figure out it was a firewall issue, however I would still like to know how to log errors ELMAH hits--or at least output something in the console--in case other issues arrive in the future.

Comment: @Zugwalt I think if there were any, You would see. It's a problem with e-mail sending - You send it and can't really make sure it has reached its destination.

Comment: I just realized I never closed the loop on this.  The e-mails were getting foiled by a network load balancer.  And from looking at things, checking out Elmah's source would be what is needed.

Answer (score 1):

have you checked the servers application event log?

Comment: There is nothing in the application event log except the original error--and I would love to know how to put something about the error Elmah hit there!